# I am having an issue getting two users to access the admin page

Tags: php, html

I am having an issue trying to get two users or more to access the admin page. I tried adding a || between them but it does not work for either of them. User here in the example is xgrh and zeap. Any help would be appreciated not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['uid']) || $_SESSION['lanId'] != 'xgrh'|| $_SESSION['lanId'] != 'zeap') {
        header('refresh:2;url=http://a0319p528/dc399supplies/index.php');

        echo "
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='panel panel-danger'>
                <div class='panel-heading'> <h3>Access Denied!!  You will now be redirected back</h3></div>
                <div class='panel-body'><img src='../admin.jpg'></div>
            </div>
        </div>";                 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Change the || to && ... But thats not going to be very flexible for more users. You'll need to expand on it, and work with a different variable to determine if they have access or not. Beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: that worked for more than one user. Please post this as an answer to get credit

Comment: Actually I think I got it wrong. Didn't see the bang on the isset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your example code, to check if the user is not signed in, and not one of the two allowed... this would work:

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION['uid']) or 
     ( $_SESSION['lanId'] != 'xgrh' and $_SESSION['lanId'] != 'zeap' ) )
{
    ... denied code ...
}
```

Checks first if no one is set. Then if neither are the right user.

If either of those two cases are true (thus the mixed 'or' and 'and'), then they are denied access.

You can also do it like this:

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION['uid']) or !in_array($_SESSION['lanId'],array('xgrh','zeap')) )
{
    ... denied code ...
}
```